# How to create a COM visible dll in F#

Tags: excel, vba, f#, com

My aim is to create a COM Visible Type that can be imported into VBA (Excel) and consumed there.

The Excel Object Browser can see my class but not any public methods of the class and fails on the attempt at calling a public method.

My F# Code:

```
namespace DotNetLibrary
type public Class1() = 
    member public  this.DotNetMethod (x:string) = "Hello" + x
```

In the AssemblyInfo.fs I also amend to `[<assembly: ComVisible(true)>]`

I run regasm with switches of `/codebase /tlb` and a .tlb file is generated.

VBA finds my library in the references browser but does not pick up the `DotNetMethod` defined on `Class1` above.

I have tried to follow the C# guidance for this topic in getting to where I am at the moment but I'm not getting to the finish line.

Comment: I seem to remember that you have to create an interface and add attributes to it and all its members.

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/example-com-class

Comment: PS: I found Excel-DNA to be a much better way of making C#/F# methods available to Excel than using COM.

Comment: COM heavily relies on interfaces, the implementation is hidden from view behind an object factory.  Classes are not directly visible by design, the default [ClassInterface] attribute is ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch so the class is only usable by late binding.  Which is fine, but the VBA editor much prefers AutoDual so it can provide auto-completion.  Explicitly declaring the interface is best.

Comment: @MarkPattison I'm aware of Excel-DNA but am under the impression that it is more for Excel-Wide add-ins than it is for single workbook interop with .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Run-Time Errors

The reason that VBA could not run the method succesfully is because I used the 32-bit version of the regasm utility instead of the 64-bit version to register the type library for COM. Given that I am using 64-bit Excel it needed 64-bit COM type libraries.

## Compile-Time Issues

The reason that VBA could not identify the methods in the IDE could be related to the above, but is also likely to be due to the interface issues raised by 
@HansPassant in his comments above.